# How can I remove duplicates in an object array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object like this:

```
class FanStruct{
    public $date; 
    public $userid;

    function __construct($date, $id){
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->userid = $id;
    }
}
```

I have maximum of 30 of them in an array, and they are sorted by `$userid`.

What is the best way to go though the array, and remove duplicate objects based on `$userid` (ignoring `$date`)?

Comment: Although this is an old question and there's already a good accepted answer, it's worth mention you can (and should) use SORT_REGULAR as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18203564/1412157

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple test that at least should get you started.  Your __toString method might need to be more elaborate to generate uniqueness for your instances of FanStruct

```
<?php

class FanStruct{
    public $date;
    public $userid;

    function __construct($date, $id){
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->userid = $id;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
      return $this->date . $this->userid;
    }
}

$test = array(
  new FanStruct( 'today', 1 )
  ,new FanStruct( 'today', 1 )
  ,new FanStruct( 'tomorrow', 1 )
);

print_r( array_unique( $test ) );

?>
```

Comment: Since 5.2.9 you don't need the `__toString()` anymore, it will work based on `(object)$x == (object)$y` comparisons when you use `SORT_REGULAR`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = array($fans[$x]);
for(var $x=1;$x<sizeof($fans);$x++) {
  if ($fans[$x]->userid != $fans[$x]->userid)
     $temp[] = $fans[$x];
}
```

Requires a temporary variable, but works.