# I have this object and I need to remove the repeated rfcs from the catalog, how is it possible to do this?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, object

I have this object in php:

```
$object = 
[
    [
        {"catalogo": "C400047", "rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4", },
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4",},   
    ],
]
```

and it should stay like this, that I eliminate all the repeated rfc of each catalog, the repeated catalogs should not be eliminated

```
[
    [
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4",},
    ],
]
```

I have tried to do this but it removes all the rfcs and I need it to remove only the repeated rfcs but by catalog

```
  for ($i=0; $i < count($object); $i++) { 
                 if(!in_array($object[$i]->rfc_inf_aval, $array1)){
                     array_push($array1,  $object[$i]->rfc_inf_aval);
                      array_push($array2,  $object[$i]);
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Ok, so show us your best attempt

Comment: PS you $object is in fact an array of objects

Comment: What is your original data? JSON?

Comment: this is original json  [
        {"catalogo": "C400047", "rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4", },
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6",},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4",},   
    ],

Comment: Well is nearly JSON :) Its fixable by removing the lazy commas

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah, but not me :-)

Comment: _this is original json_ Then its invalid JSON, try putting it into `https://jsonlint.com`

Comment: I need with an algorithm to make the first array of objects be like the second from some algorithm. the object is created from a database query the query is this SELECT catalog,rfc_inf_guarantee from V_ANEXO_18_IFRS9_GARANTE

Comment: I know what you need, but uinless the data is valid JSON then it cannot be done, well not by me as I am not going to try and remove allthe LAZY trailing commas. PHP allows them now but JSON does not

Comment: _the object is created from a database query_ Then you need to look at whatever is storing this data, either it is turning JSON into nonsense or you are building JSON manually somewhere and its not being done right

Comment: checkout `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` If you are building JSON an other way, you run the risk of creating invalid json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Removing duplicate objects from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558484/php-removing-duplicate-objects-from-array)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 for ($i=0; $i < count($object); $i++) { 
     $k = $object[$i]->catalogo.'|'.$object[$i]->rfc_inf_aval;
     $reduced[$k] = $object[$i];
 }
 $object = array_values($reduced);
```

- I generate a key from catalogo and rfc_inf_aval. That eliminates the duplication in the new array.
- `array_values` just sets normal numeric indexes in the result array.

Comment: If the OP can find a way to get valid JSON and convert it to a PHP Array of objects, this works very nicely :) Would have used a foreach myself, but thats just semantics

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh, i just updated his last code snippet, with the `for` :-) And only was taking the code snippet and "I need it to remove only the repeated rfcs but by catalog" into account for my answer.

Comment: @christianalvarez nice :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, your object is invalid, since is a JSON string, so I use heredoc to define it.

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25020035/1757214 I get the following code:

```
<?php 

$js = <<<JSON
[[
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4"},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6"},
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6"},
        {"catalogo": "C400047","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4"},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6"},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6"},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "MZT8501014S6"},
        {"catalogo": "C140064","rfc_inf_aval": "CIS981002NK4"} 
]]
JSON;
// Get the real object as an associative array
$data = json_decode($js, true);
// Use the first element, since is a nested array
$object = $data[0];

function my_array_unique($array, $keep_key_assoc = false){
    $duplicate_keys = array();
    $tmp = array();       

    foreach ($array as $key => $val){
        // convert objects to arrays, in_array() does not support objects
        if (is_object($val))
            $val = (array)$val;

        if (!in_array($val, $tmp))
            $tmp[] = $val;
        else
            $duplicate_keys[] = $key;
    }

    foreach ($duplicate_keys as $key)
        unset($array[$key]);

    return $keep_key_assoc ? $array : array_values($array);
}

var_dump(my_array_unique($object));
```

You will get:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["catalogo"]=>
    string(7) "C400047"
    ["rfc_inf_aval"]=>
    string(12) "CIS981002NK4"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["catalogo"]=>
    string(7) "C140064"
    ["rfc_inf_aval"]=>
    string(12) "MZT8501014S6"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["catalogo"]=>
    string(7) "C400047"
    ["rfc_inf_aval"]=>
    string(12) "MZT8501014S6"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["catalogo"]=>
    string(7) "C140064"
    ["rfc_inf_aval"]=>
    string(12) "CIS981002NK4"
  }
}
```