# Create unique array as per one of the array element

Tags: php, arrays, elgg

I have the following array in PHP. Its an array of objects. I am trying to create an unique array from it.

```
array
  0 => 
    object(ElggAnnotation)[1144]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '21705' (length=5)
          'owner_guid' => string '40468' (length=5)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1406098167' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)
      private 'valid' (ElggExtender) => boolean false
  1 => 
    object(ElggAnnotation)[1145]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '21706' (length=5)
          'owner_guid' => string '28715' (length=5)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1406098168' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'scheduled' (length=9)
          'value' => string 'yes' (length=3)
          'type' => string 'annotation' (length=10)
      private 'valid' (ElggExtender) => boolean false
  2 => 
    object(ElggAnnotation)[1146]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '21707' (length=5)
          'owner_guid' => string '40468' (length=5)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1406104062' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)           
      private 'valid' (ElggExtender) => boolean false
  3 => 
    object(ElggAnnotation)[1147]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '21708' (length=5)
          'owner_guid' => string '28715' (length=5)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1406104062' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)              
      private 'valid' (ElggExtender) => boolean false
  4 => 
    object(ElggAnnotation)[1148]
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array
          'id' => string '21709' (length=5)
          'owner_guid' => string '40468' (length=5)
          'access_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'time_created' => string '1406104195' (length=10)
          'enabled' => string 'yes' (length=3)              
      private 'valid' (ElggExtender) => boolean false
```

So i need to create a unique array as per its element `'owner_guid'` ...I tried `array_unique` method..but its didn't worked for me ...

How do it guys ? Any idea ?

Comment: whats the error message for using array_unique??

Comment: @Torrezzzz No error message its getting blank

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426557/array-unique-for-objects

Comment: @Torrezzzz its seems to be very different what i am looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$unique = array();

foreach($objects as $object) {
    $unique[$object->owner_guid] = $object;
}

var_dump($unique);
```

Comment: @RIADev `$unique` will contain 1 object per `owner_guid`, you can get the unique `owner_guid` by `array_keys($unique)`

Comment: Hey that can be done so easily...but what my question by using owner_guid can i make the master array unique

Comment: @RIADev that's what this does ... try it, if it doesn't work post your expected output in the question