# Remove duplicate using array_unique

Tags: php, foreach, array-unique

Hi I'm trying to loop through a list of tags using wordpress. The list of tags is generated through another plugin.

at present this is the code I have

```
    <?php foreach($entities as $entity): ?>
    <?php $str = str_replace(' ', '-', esc_attr($entity->galdesc)) ?>
    <li><a href="#" id="<?php echo $str ?>"><?php echo_safe_html(nl2br($entity->galdesc)); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

This outputs the list of tags as follows

```
    tag1
    tag1
    tag2
    tag1
    tag3
```

this goes on with all the tags but I'm trying to remove the duplicates, I've looked into using array_unique but cant get this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to format new array with $entity->galdesc and then call array_unique on it ?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about this? I've tried various things but i just know I'm not doing something right...

Comment: http://ideone.com/3Quu4I

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cache the values of $entity->galdesc you already used.
An approach with [in_array](http://php.net/in-array) could look like this:

```
<?php $tagnamesUsed = array(); ?>
<?php foreach($entities as $entity): ?>
<?php $str = str_replace(' ', '-', esc_attr($entity->galdesc)) ?>
<?php if (!in_array($entity->galdesc, $tagnamesUsed)): ?>
<li><a href="#" id="<?php echo $str ?>"><?php echo_safe_html(nl2br($entity->galdesc)); ?></a></li>
<?php $tagnamesUsed[] = $entity->galdesc; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains objects. `array_unique()` tries to compare your array values as strings. See the top answer here for more detail: [array_unique for objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426557/array-unique-for-objects)

One way to solve this is to create an array of tags that have already been output, then check against it each time:

```
<?php $arrTags = array(); ?>
<?php foreach($entities as $entity): ?>
   <?php $str = str_replace(' ', '-', esc_attr($entity->galdesc)) ?>

   <?php if(in_array($str,$arrTags)){ continue; } else { $arrTags[] = $str; } ?>

   <li><a href="#" id="<?php echo $str ?>"><?php echo_safe_html(nl2br($entity->galdesc)); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate the array of entities twice, it's not fancy but probably will work.

1. Parse the tag title and add it to a temp array
2. Apply the array_unique in the temp array
3. Iterate the temp array to print the result

**The code for it will be something like this:**

```
<?php

$tmp = array();
foreach($entities as $entity) {
    $tmp[] = str_replace(' ', '-', esc_attr($entity->galdesc));
}

$uniques = array_unique($tmp);
foreach ($uniques as $entity) {
    echo $entity . '<br>';
}
```