# PHP taking an array of objects, get rid of the duplicates one

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have this array:-

```
$arr
: array = 
  0: object(myObject) = 
    id: string = 188
    CaseNo: string = 1
    strname: string = Apple
    strContact: string = Alice
  1: object(myObject) = 
    id: string = 188
    CaseNo: string = 1
    strname: string = Apple
    strContact: string = Alice
  2: object(myObject) = 
    id: string = 189
    CaseNo: string = 3
    strname: string = Amazon
    strContact: string = Jules
```

As you can see, the two first objects in the array are repeated, how can get the same array without the repeated object, meaning:

```
$arr
: array = 
  0: object(myObject) = 
    id: string = 188
    CaseNo: string = 1
    strname: string = Apple
    strContact: string = Alice
  1: object(myObject) = 
    id: string = 189
    CaseNo: string = 3
    strname: string = Amazon
    strContact: string = Jules
```

Please notice that this is an example array. The number of items in the array can be more than three and the number of repeated objects inside of it can be more than two.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array\_unique for objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426557/array-unique-for-objects)

Comment: you see that question ? I think you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426557/array-unique-for-objects

Comment: $arr= array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $arr)));
echo "<pre/>";print_r($arr);

Comment: Miguel Mas  its your responsibility to check the answer and mark and up-vote the answer which is correct and more descriptive for you. Please do it. It will help others. Stack work in this way only.

Comment: people are not responding and didn't feel there responsibility

Answer (score 0):

Use array unique function which used to remove duplication

```
 $a = array(
        0 => array (
            "ID" => 188,
            "CaseNo" => 1,
            "strname" => 'Apple',
            "strContact" => 'Alies'

        ),
        1 => array (
             "ID" => 188,
            "CaseNo" => 1,
            "strname" => 'Apple',
            "strContact" => 'Alies'

        ),
        2 => array (
            "ID" => 189,
            "CaseNo" => 1,
            "strname" => 'Amazon',
            "strContact" => 'Jules'

        ),
);
echo "<pre>";
$ab = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $a)));
print_r($ab);
```