# how to remove duplicate entry from array objet

Tags: php

Morning I'm working on a project and  I have a issue, it's about to know how to remove duplicate entry from an array object .

Here is structure of my array :

```
"IDGROUP": [
                {
                    "id": 72
                },
                {
                    "id": 72
                }
            ]
```

Here is code snippet:

```
 if($compteGroupes && $compteGroupes->getId()!=0){

          $Tableaux_pack[$current_id_fictif]["ingroup"]]=
                          $Mes_comptes_reels_dependants [$taille_reel];

            $Tableaux_pack[$current_id_fictif]["IDGROUP"]= 
                             array(
                                 'id'=>$compteGroupes->getId()      
                                 );

                            }
```

thank's for your  help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Comment: when I use array_unique() the issue still happen

Comment: my goal is to remove  duplicates of objects sharing same property value

Answer (score 0):

Your object looks like a javascript object - what do you actually mean?

are the entries classes? are they arrays

do you want to filter nested/multidimensional arrays based on their values?

do you want to filter different class objects?
see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2426579/8548024

Comment: when I loop on  this  array $Tableaux_pack[$current_id_fictif]["IDGROUP"] I need check if  value $compteGroupes->getId() is allready inside before adding it