# Get the two different objects together

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection, laravel-controller

I've got `$campus_groups` coming from `CampusGroup`

```
$campus_groups = CampusGroup::where('campus_id', $campus_id)->get();
```

which has

```
[
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"group_id":1,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"},
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"group_id":2,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"group_id":5,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z"}
]
```

and `$campus_org_groups` coming from `CampusOrganizationGroup`

```
$campus_org_groups = CampusOrganizationGroup::where('campus_id', $campus_id)->get();
```

which has

```
[
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"campus_organization_id":1,"group_id":3,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"},
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"campus_organization_id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"campus_organization_id":1,"group_id":6,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z"}
]
```

and would like to get both together like this (the important key is `group_id` and I'm ok if `campus_organization_id` is left out)

```
[
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"group_id":1,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"},
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"group_id":2,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"group_id":5,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z"},
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"group_id":3,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"},
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"group_id":6,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z"}
]
```

---

If I [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge) them

```
$obj_merged = $campus_groups->merge($campus_org_groups);
```

this is what I'm getting

```
[
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"campus_organization_id":1,"group_id":3,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"},
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"campus_organization_id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"campus_organization_id":1,"group_id":6,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z"}
]
```

If I [union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-union) them

```
$obj_merged = $campus_groups->union($campus_org_groups);
```

this is what I'm getting

```
[
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"group_id":1,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"},   
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"group_id":2,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"group_id":5,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z"}
]
```

Comment: Ok, so that's what you're getting. What do you **want**?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular it's explained in the question

Comment: Not really. "_would like to get both together_" is the only indication of what you want. Please post an example of the results you're after

Comment: @brombeer just included that. In other words, the `group_id` is the key of interest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [array\_unique for objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426557/array-unique-for-objects)

Comment: Have you tried  `$campus_groups + $campus_org_groups` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed

```
$campus_groups = CampusGroup::where('campus_id', $campus_id)->get();
$campus_org_groups = CampusOrganizationGroup::where('campus_id', $campus_id)->get();
```

to

```
$campus_groups = collect(CampusGroup::where('campus_id', $campus_id)->get(['id','campus_id','group_id','created_at','updated_at'])); 
$campus_org_groups = collect(CampusOrganizationGroup::where('campus_id', $campus_id)->get(['id','campus_id','group_id','created_at','updated_at']));
```

Notice the usage of `collect()` and also specification of the fields I really wanted (leaving out `campus_organization_id`). Then, the initial merge

```
$obj_merged = $campus_groups->merge($campus_org_groups);
```

would return the desired output

```
[
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"group_id":1,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"},
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"group_id":2,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:37.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"group_id":5,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:16:49.000000Z"},
    {"id":1,"campus_id":1,"group_id":3,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"},
    {"id":2,"campus_id":1,"group_id":4,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:15:55.000000Z"},
    {"id":3,"campus_id":1,"group_id":6,"created_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-15T08:17:28.000000Z"}
]
```

Comment: `->get()` will return collection, there's no difference using `collect()`

Comment: @shyammakwana.me then why the output is different then?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer.

Comment: @mohammadasghari oh sure, I always do that!

Answer (score 1):

Could you test this solution:

```
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $campus_groups, (array) $campus_org_groups);
```

Comment: I'm not able to return that but if I dd() it, can see only `{#1402 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\CampusOrganizationGroup {#1420 ▶}
    1 => App\CampusOrganizationGroup {#1421 ▶}
    2 => App\CampusOrganizationGroup {#1422 ▶}
  ]
}`

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple operation, `array_merge` should work

```
<?php $campus_groups = [
['id' => 1, 'campus_id'=> 1, 'group_id'=> 1],
['id' => 2, 'campus_id'=> 1, 'group_id'=> 2],
['id' => 3, 'campus_id'=> 1, 'group_id'=> 5],
];

$campus_org_groups = [
['id' => 1, 'campus_id'=> 1, 'group_id'=> 3, 'campus_organization_id' => 1],
['id' => 2, 'campus_id'=> 1, 'group_id'=> 4, 'campus_organization_id' => 1],
['id' => 3, 'campus_id'=> 1, 'group_id'=> 5, 'campus_organization_id' => 1],

];

print_r(array_merge($campus_groups , $campus_org_groups));
```

https://repl.it/@technoknol/StainedHealthyBlogclient

Comment: Here you made an array of array but I think he has array of object.

Comment: @MaxiGui op has posted JSON syntax, you can't really say that's array of array or array of object. I've given suggestion only.

Answer (score 1):

I did something with `array_push` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)) simple like:

```php
foreach($array2 as $val){    
    array_push($array1, $val);
}
```

Tested [here](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com) withcode below:

```php
<?php

class newObject{
    public $id;
    public $campus_id;
    public $group_id;
    public $created_at;
    public $updated_at;
    
    function create($id, $campus_id, $group_id, $created_at, $updated_at){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->campus_id = $campus_id;
        $this->group_id = $group_id;
        $this->created_at = $created_at;
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;
        
    }
    
}

class newObject2{
    public $id;
    public $campus_id;
    public $campus_organization_id;
    public $group_id;
    public $created_at;
    public $updated_at;
    
    function create($id, $campus_id, $campus_organization_id, $group_id, $created_at, $updated_at){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->campus_id = $campus_id;
        $this->campus_organization_id = $campus_organization_id;
        $this->group_id = $group_id;
        $this->created_at = $created_at;
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;
        
    }
    
}

$newObject = new newObject;
$newObject->create("1", "1", "1", "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z", "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z");

$newObjectA = new newObject;
$newObjectA->create("2", "1", "1", "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z", "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z");

$array1 = [$newObject, $newObjectA];

$newObject2 = new newObject2;
$newObject2->create("1", "1", "1", "3", "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z", "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z");

$newObject2A = new newObject2;
$newObject2A->create("2", "1", "1", "3", "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z", "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z");

$array2 = [$newObject2, $newObject2A];

foreach($array2 as $val){
    
    array_push($array1, $val);
}

var_dump($array1);
```

Output final:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(newObject)#1 (5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["campus_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["group_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(newObject)#2 (5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["campus_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["group_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:27.000000Z"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(newObject2)#3 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["campus_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["campus_organization_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["group_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(newObject2)#4 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["campus_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["campus_organization_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["group_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(27) "2021-03-15T08:15:50.000000Z"
  }
}
```